# End note reference not in superscript

Tags: endnotes

For an article I write, I am using the `endnotes` package – I am a newbie and I cannot achieve the following:

- how to have reference in text like mytext [1] instead of mytext<sup>1</sup>

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[]{jacow}
\begin{document}
\section{Rationale}\label{rationale}

    Over the last 26 years, \emph{mytext}\endnote{\url{http://dummylink.com}} has been the main system we used.

\end
```

I have no idea what to change.

Looking on the web I successfully changed the reference in the final notes
section to have the square brackets:

```
\patchcmd{\theendnotes}
  {\makeatletter}
  {\makeatletter\renewcommand\makeenmark{[\theenmark] }}
  {}{}
```

I would like to do the same for the reference in text itself.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please edit your post to add a MWE (see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/120578). You can add code from the file that you say you successfully changed. Also please make your question more clear (the "with '1' in superscript" stuff is not really clear... You can give an image or something to make clear what result you expect)

Comment: @koleygr edited following your comments.

Comment: You are not making an MWE, we cannot test your code as is, there is no preamble, documentclass etc. Help us help you by providing something we can just copy and test as is.

Comment: @clemens: ok thanks. But it's changing end notes in the notes not in the text.

Comment: @mguijarr I don't understand what you mean. Anyway, I deleted my comment and added an answer

Comment: @clemens sorry I thought I already tried that but not in fact ;) Your solution works. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: By the way regarging ”looking in the web“ – the first place to look should be the manual of the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only put `\renewcommand\makeenmark{[\theenmark] }` in your preamble (without the `\patchcmd` business) then *every* mark will be changed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes,etoolbox}

% the mark everywhere:
\renewcommand\makeenmark{[\theenmark]}

% the mark in the list of endnotes -- we need an extra space:
\patchcmd{\theendnotes}
  {\makeatletter}
  {\makeatletter\renewcommand\makeenmark{[\theenmark] }}% notice the space!
  {}{}
\begin{document}

Text\endnote{bla} text

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]